# Ubuntu system won't load

Tags: ubuntu-touch

For my smart home, I have an old comuter

For some time, all of the versions won't start.. all I get is black screen, I have access to grub v 2.02
What can I do to boot it without loosing all the data inside?
It is vital to save everything

When I try in root mode to write the line you gave me for the card, it's says: w: not using locked for read only files. E: unable to write to /car/catch/apt. E: the package lists it status file could not be parsed or opened.
When I try to boot normal I get the blue screen with the the Ubuntu 14.04 and the dots blinking for about 10 sec, and then black screen fore as long as I'm doing nothing, when I press the shutdown button, it's shut down properly: wait for start/stop... and shutting all the process

Comment: try booting through a live USB, if that's possible, then you can take the backup of your data and decide what to do next, because reinstalling does delete data

Answer (score 0):

You do not give us anything to go on except for "blank screen". Please update your question with more details if you find anything.

If you data is vital why is this an issue? You can reinstall your system and restore a backup. When data is vital you have several backups and made one before and after each big change to your system, you also periodically restore said backup to know it is restorable. Otherwise "vital" is an insult to how precious your data is.

If you do not have a backup: boot up a live session and make a backup of your data, make sure you can restore it and only then start investigating your problem by looking at log files in /var/log/ to scan for errors, critical errors and notices that are related to your video card.

Next find out how to restore your video card driver (blank screens tend to be related to video card drivers) and see if that fixes it. You can do this from a live session. You did not include what your video card is; if you do know what it is include it into the question. If intel this should work:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Here is another for nvidia: [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics)

- Make sure you have internet access while you do this (from the live session you can enter a wireless password for your connection if you need wireless active).

If all fails: reinstall and restore the backup you made.

Comment: How can I load pics to the site? I'll show you

Comment: All you need to do is upload it somewhere and add the link to the question and someone will make it a picture  (you need reputation to do that yourself ).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you meant with "*When I try in root mode to write the line you gave me for the card*"? Who gave you what command, and how/where did you try to enter it? Either you forgot to make the drive read/write, or you entered the command wrong, or...

From your brief description, it sounds like you **may** have a hard disk drive that has got errors, and then goes into read-only mode to protect itself from further damage.

Lets first check your file system for errors.

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`